# Change the position of an image on mousemove

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the position of the image when mouse move but the image doesn't change even if position is changed when I did `console.log`

```js
var image = document.getElementById('img')

image.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  console.log(e.pageX * -1 / 12)
  var valueX = (e.pageX * -1 / 12);
  var valueY = (e.pageY * -1 / 12);
  image.style.backgroundPositionX = valueX + "px"
  image.style.backgroundPositionY = valueY + "px"
});
```

```html
<header>

  <img id="img" src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">

</header>
```

```
header {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}

header img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a working demo please or maybe include the relevant `css` for the `img` tag. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it. This sample code just fleshes things out a bit and moved some stuff to the CSS.

The key change was using a `<div>` instead of a `<img>`. As you were using `backgroundPositionX` and `backgroundPositionY` in the Javascript, these values are for the background image of an element and do not work with a `<img>`. Well, they can be used there too, but the `src` will hide the background unless you use a transparent image.

```js
function mvImg(e) {
  var valueX = (e.pageX * -1 / 12);
  var valueY = (e.pageY * -1 / 12);
  this.style.backgroundPositionX = valueX + "px"
  this.style.backgroundPositionY = valueY + "px"
}
window.onload = function() {
  var im = document.getElementById("mv-img");
  if (im) {
    im.addEventListener("mousemove",mvImg,false);
  }  
}
```

```css
#mv-img {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-image:url("https://via.placeholder.com/100/456");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #192;
}
```

```html
<div id="mv-img"></div>
```

Comment: Good answer. Certainly closer than mine to the intended behavior. Comparing your code to his it's not obvious what he did wrong. Perhaps you could say in your answer what the critical change(s) were? As he is pretty clearly new to programming I imagine an explanation would be helpful.

Comment: thank you it worked , but i dont know what i did wrong

Comment: @RockySims : Some details added now that I'm back from breakfast :]

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `style="position:absolute;"` to your `img`.

Also, you need to change `backgroundPositionX` to `left` and `backgroundPositionY` to `top`.

I'm not entirely sure this is the behavior you're going for but following the above steps will cause the image to move when the mouse moves (provided the mouse is on the image).

Comment: `header` is an HTML tag and is valid. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_header.asp

Comment: @disinfor oh you're right. Thanks, I'll update my answer.